# SML tuple access

Tags: sml

As far as I know in Simple ML, tuples are being accessed via `#n`s and previously I have seen it working but now it does not work!

I have tried this following line:

```
val a =#2 ("one", "2", "three")
```

But it is giving me the following error back:

```
first.sml:25.26 Error: syntax error found at EOF

uncaught exception Compile [Compile: "syntax error"]
  raised at: ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
-
```

Weird!

Comment: I suppose that compiler interprets `=#2` as one symbolic name (# and = can be part of the identifier as well). Try to  put space between `=` and `#` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard ML allows you to define your own arbitrary operators. This means that when you mix infix and prefix operators, you need to have spaces between them - otherwise they'd be interpreted as one operator.

In other words, SML thinks you're trying to call the non-existent `=#` operator in your code. If you add a space between the `=` and the `#`, it will work fine.